# Routing when using Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

All,

I have the following code and it is not creating the expected route.

```
[RoutePrefix("widgets")]
public class PublishedReportWidgetController : Controller

    [Route("published-reports"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PublishedReports()

    [Route("published-reports/{publishedReportId}"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PublishedReports(int publishedReportId)
```

Now inside my view, I have the following :

```
console.log("@(Url.Action("PublishedReports", "PublishedReportsWidget"))");
console.log("@(Url.Action("PublishedReports", "PublishedReportsWidget", new { id = 9999 }))");
```

Now how come this does not output the route "/widgets/published-reports/9999"?

I see it does output "widgets/published-reports?9999" followed "/widgets/published-reports"

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: Does it make any difference if you keep the names the same? So instead of publishedReportId use id, as in the view?

Comment: I changed the name from '{publishedReportId}' in the controller and kept the code in my view as is and still no luck.

Still outputting '/widgets/published-reports?id=9999'

Comment: That is actually my original issue but I assume since it was rectified, I would post another issue.  Apologies if I shouldn't be doing it this way.

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out, I guess having the word 'id' vs 'publishedReportId' was causing the issue.